# iOS Developer PageControl Sample Optimization

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I am trying to implement the suggested optimization for the [iOS Developer PageControl Sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html). Here is the code I am using in the PhoneContentController:

```
// A possible optimization would be to unload the views+controllers which are no longer visible
for (int i = 0; i < page-1; i++) {
    MyViewController *vc = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
    if ((NSNull *)vc != [NSNull null]) {
        NSLog(@"Unloading page %d", i);
        [vc.view removeFromSuperview];
        vc.view = nil;
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
}

for (int i = page+2; i < kNumberOfPages; i++) {
    MyViewController *vc = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
    if ((NSNull *)vc != [NSNull null]) {
        NSLog(@"Unloading page %d", i);
        [vc.view removeFromSuperview];
        vc.view = nil;
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
}
```

This appears to work ok. However I would have expected the viewDidUnload method in the MyViewController to be executed as well as the dealloc method. I placed an NSLog() call in both of these methods:

```
 - (void)viewDidUnload
{
    NSLog(@"Page %d unloaded", pageNumber);
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Page %d destroyed", pageNumber);
    [pageNumberLabel release];
    [numberTitle release];
    [numberImage release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

It appears that only dealloc is called. Here is the output:

```
2011-12-02 01:13:38.829 PageControl[3560:207] Unloading page 0
2011-12-02 01:13:38.831 PageControl[3560:207] Page 0 destroyed
2011-12-02 01:13:39.597 PageControl[3560:207] Unloading page 1
2011-12-02 01:13:39.598 PageControl[3560:207] Page 1 destroyed
2011-12-02 01:13:40.437 PageControl[3560:207] Unloading page 2
2011-12-02 01:13:40.437 PageControl[3560:207] Page 2 destroyed
```

My question is: why isn't viewDidUnload called?

Simulating an low-memory warning does not make any difference.

I inserted NSLog statements as follows:

```
if ((NSNull *)vc != [NSNull null]) {
    UIView *vw = vc.view;
    NSLog(@"1.vw[%d] -> %d", i, [vw retainCount]);
    [vc.view removeFromSuperview];
    NSLog(@"2.vw[%d] -> %d", i, [vw retainCount]);
    vc.view = nil;
    NSLog(@"3.vw[%d] -> %d", i, [vw retainCount]);
    [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNull null]];
    NSLog(@"4.vw[%d] -> %d", i, [vw retainCount]);
}
```

The retainCount starts at 3. It stays at 3 after vc.view is removed from the superview. It drops to 2 after vc.view is set to nil. it stays at 2 after the vc is removed from the viewControllers array.

My question is (still): why isn't viewDidUnload called?

Regards and thanks in advance

Comment: `retainCount` is useless.  Don't call it.

Answer (score 0):

From [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) reference for `viewDidUnload`

> When a low-memory condition occurs and the current view controller’s
>   views are not needed, the system may opt to remove those views from
>   memory. This method is called after the view controller’s view has
>   been released and is your chance to perform any final cleanup.

viewDidUnload will only happen when the system removes those views from memory. Those methods should get fired if you issue a memory warning on your simulator under the Hardware menu.

Comment: I tried issuing an memory warning on the simulator but that did not call viewDidUnload either. If I print [vc.view retainCount] before and after removing it from the superview I get values of 3 and 2 respectively.

Comment: Again, viewDidUnload will only be called when the memory is freed. If your retain counts are higher than 0, the memory wont be freed, and viewDidUnload wont be called. So now the question is: Why are your retains greater than 0?

Comment: Exactly. This is what I don't understand. I would have thought the retain count should be two: the MyViewController and the UIScrollView retain the view. I don't understand why it is three. Also I don't understand why the retain count does not decrease when it is removed from its superview (the UIScrollView).